# How do I compare data range between dates type "TEXT"

Tags: php, mysql

I need to compare 2 dates type "TEXT".
My question is, I have date that is exist in the database, and the other date is not existing. How to make query that compare 2 dates type "TEXT", first date is exist, and 2nd date is not. Here is my example data in database 2017 and 2016

[image: This is example date 2017]

[image: This is example date 2016]

My Query is `SELECT * FROM oec2 WHERE oec_month BETWEEN '$oec_month1' AND '$oec_month2'`
Note: the $oec_month1 (date type TEXT) is exist in db, but the $oec_month2 is not exist.

If I used that query it give me the result of 2017 and 2016
[image: The Result]

```
$db = new ezSQL_mysqli(db_user,db_password,db_name,db_host);

$field='date';
$sort='ASC';
if (isset($_GET['search'])){
$branch_id = $db->escape((int)($_GET['branch_id']));
$branch_region = $_GET['branch_region'];    
$oec_month1 = $_GET['oec_month1'];
$oec_month2 = $_GET['oec_month2'];
if(isset($_GET['sorting'])){
    if($_GET['sorting']=='ASC'){$sort='DESC';$dir="down";}
    else {$sort='ASC';$dir="up";}
}
if ($_GET['field']=='result'){$field="result";}
else if ($_GET['field']=='oecgrade'){$field="oecgrade";}
else if ($_GET['field']=='risk'){$field="risk";}



if (!empty($oec_month1)) {
    if (!empty($oec_month2)){$searchquery .= " AND (oec_month BETWEEN '$oec_month1' AND '$oec_month2')";}
    else {$searchquery .= " AND oec_month >= '$oec_month1'";}
} else if (!empty($oec_month2)){$searchquery .= " AND oec_month <= '$oec_month2'";}
if (!empty($branch_id)) {$searchquery .= " AND (branch_id = '$branch_id')";}
if (!empty($branch_region)) {$searchquery .= " AND (branch_region = '$branch_region')";}
$searchquery .= (" order by $field $sort;");
$site_oec = $db->get_results("SELECT * FROM oec2 WHERE 1=1 $searchquery");
$num = $db->num_rows;
```

The final output should be the only data in 2017 because the user pick dates between "01/2017" and "02/2017", but it gives me the result of 2016. FYI: The date "02/2017" is not exist.

Comment: No pictures thanks. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

You can use `STR_TO_DATE()` to convert TEXT into appropriate supported date format, then it would be possible to compare values between date.

**Example:**

If `$oec_month1` and `$oec_month1` contains date format as:

```
$oec_month1 = "01/2017";
$oec_month2 = "01/2017";
```

Then, it may be something like this example:

```
SELECT * FROM oec2 WHERE oec_month >= STR_TO_DATE($oec_month1, '%m/%Y') AND oec_month <= STR_TO_DATE($oec_month2, '%m/%Y')
```

For further information about date format please see the link below:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: Thankyou for answer. your query is working. but how about the $oec_month2 which is contain "02/2017" that is not exist in db ? The result of your query has no output if $oec_month1="01/2017" and $oec_month2="02/2017"

Comment: Please can you share your `php` code here and also try my updated answer and tell me if working or not

Comment: I have date "01/2017" in database. But I dont have date "02/2017"
I need to make an output from the choosen date 1 and date 2.
For example: User choose date 1 as "01/2017" which is in database. and date 2 as "02/2017" which is NOT in database.
If I used my old query it give me result of 2017 including 2016. It should give result of 2017 only because the user pick range between "01/2017" and "02/2017"